# AngularJS delay view load

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to delay the ui-view till the DOM loads. At the minute i'll click a page and the images are only half loaded. Is there a good way to only display the new page load once all the elements have been loaded completely?

I have tried using `ng-cloak`but I don't think it does what I need.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using angular routing you ca use `resolve` for that. You can read more about it in [angular routing documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#dependencies).

Resolve accept promises and won't let view be shown untill those promises are resolved.

**upd**:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('navigation', ['myControllers', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/MyPage/',
            {
                controller: 'myController',
                controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/AngularApp/Modules/MyPage/Views/index.html',
                // here we create a promise and it will be resolved in 2 seconds and then page will be loaded.
                resolve: { tmp: function ($timeout) { return $timeout(function () { }, 2000); } } 
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
})();
```

Here we describe our routing and create empty promise to mock data loading process. But in real world you'll want to put a `$http` call there (it will get your data from server). Fortunately `$http` returns promise.

Comment: Thanks, i've found some good documentation on google but i'm only just getting started with angularjs so i'm having some difficulties. Do I add the promises in and then they call methods in the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to hide your images until they are loaded. You can do this by using a directive as an attribute (similar to how ng-cloak works but with added functionality). Your directive would look something like this, first hiding the element when angular compiles, and then showing it when the document is ready / images have loaded, etc.

```
angular.module('app').directive('fadeUpWhenReady', ['$document', function ($document) {
  return { 
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function (element, attr) {
      element.css({
        "opacity": 0,
        "-webkit-transform":  "translateY(100px)",
        "-moz-transform":     "translateY(100px)",
        "-o-transform":       "translateY(100px)",
        "-ms-transform":      "translateY(100px)",
        "transform":          "translateY(100px)",
        "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.345, 0, 0.25, 1)",
        "-moz-transition":    "all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.345, 0, 0.25, 1)",
        "-o-transition":      "all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.345, 0, 0.25, 1)",
        "-ms-transition":     "all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.345, 0, 0.25, 1)",
        "transition":         "all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.345, 0, 0.25, 1)"
      });

      $document.ready( function() {
        element.css({
          "opacity": 1,
          "-webkit-transform":  "translateY(0)",
          "-moz-transform":     "translateY(0)",
          "-o-transform":       "translateY(0)",
          "-ms-transform":      "translateY(0)",
          "transform":          "translateY(0)"
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Finally, you just use it as an attribute in an element you'd like to hide, for example:

```
<img ng-src = "{{ img.url }}" fade-up-when-ready />
```

Note that if your element is inside an `ui-view`, it'll compile twice. Once when the page initially loads, and a second time when the `ui-view` comes in the screen.